# What's the most semantically correct way to do subheadings?

Tags: html, semantics

What's the most semantically correct way to do subheadings or subtitles? Example below.

---

### About

#### <sup>We sell apples, yay!</sup>

Lorem ipsum...

---

Since the contents of the subheading aren't of much importance when compared to actual, informative headings, I thought that they should not be seen as separate headings by screen readers and search engines.

So, the options that I thought of are as follows:

- `<h2>About</h2><h3>We sell apples, yay!</h3>` -> This is what I would like to avoid.
- `<h2>About</h2><span class="subheading">We sell apples, yay!</span>` -> Works. Is it the best way? Don't know.
- `<h2>About<span class="subheading">We sell apples, yay!</span></h2>` -> Part of the heading. I don't really know if it's a good or bad thing.

Any advice on this one?

Comment: If you don't consider your sub-headings to be important enough to qualify as actual headings, why are you using them at all? Why, specifically, do you oppose using the various `<H2>`/`<H3>`/etc. tags?

Comment: @Cody I consider lines like "We sell apples, yay!" more like a decorative element than a heading. Byline seems to be the appropriate term.

Comment: Whoever told you that you mean to use the term "byline" is wrong. A "byline" is "a line in a newpaper indicating the author of the article." Literally, it's a "line" showing who the article is "by." I think you mean a "subtitle" (definition 2), which the Oxford American defines as "a subordinate title of a published work or article giving additional information about its content."

Comment: @AlanH. I guess you're right. It's been so long I have no recollection where I got the term. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

HTML5 solves this by way of the `hgroup` tag. Use that.

If you feel you're not yet ready to migrate, then I'd say you should still go with proper heading tags whenever you're marking up a heading. If you feel uncomfortable marking up two headings as siblings, perhaps you can adjust your copy to reduce the number of headings to just one.

**Edit**:

Since the time of writing, the future of `hgroup` has been endangered: http://dev.w3.org/html5/status/issue-status.html#ISSUE-164

**Edit 2**:

As of April 2nd 2013 `hgroup` is removed from the spec:
http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html-admin/2013Apr/0003.html

(Source: https://twitter.com/iandevlin/status/318961224836587521)

**Edit 3**:

It seems that hgroup is back, but with a notable change to what kind of content it should contain:

> The element may be used to group an h1–h6 element with one or more p elements containing content representing a subheading, alternative title, or tagline.
> (source: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/sections.html#the-hgroup-element)

Comment: +1 for noting that HTML 5 has better support for situations like this.

Comment: I had no idea there's such tag. Thanks!

Comment: Since the time of writing, the future of `hgroup` has been endangered: http://dev.w3.org/html5/status/issue-status.html#ISSUE-164

Comment: @nikc.org so what is the proper solution now that hgroup is obsolete?

Comment: @deathlock - using `header` to group content seems to be an appropriate idiom. See my updated answer, and http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/common-idioms.html#sub-head

Comment: The W3C dropped `<hgroup>` from the HTML5 specification.

Comment: @wolle yep, in 2013, as you can see in the edits section of my answer.

Comment: MDN hasn't marked hgroup as deprecated and I found a few pages on the W3 website that don't say anything to that effect, so I'm going to assume hgroup is okay to use after all. If not, please provide a source. According to whatwg.org, hgroup is a living standard: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/sections.html#the-hgroup-element

Comment: @hawk interesting. There is a notable change though: the content is now specified to be one heading (h1-h6) with one or more p tags. I've updated my answer, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 19):

### Spec

- https://www.w3.org/TR/html51/common-idioms-without-dedicated-elements.html#subheadings-subtitles-alternative-titles-and-taglines

> h1–h6 elements must not be used to markup subheadings, subtitles,
>   alternative titles and taglines unless intended to be the heading for
>   a new section or subsection.

A heading should help comprise the outline of the document. The document outline in Microsoft Word—which also uses headings 1 - 6—is a good example of this concept in action. Headings often serve (or have the potential to serve) as the title for some additional body of information, that is, "headings for the sections with which they are associated".

If the content does not help form the outline of the document and has no potential to be a title for other information, then it probably doesn't belong in a `H[1-6]` tag.

### Example

> A header typically contains a **group** of introductory or navigational aids.
>   <sub>http://www.w3.org/TR/html51/sections.html#the-header-element, emphasis mine.</sub>

```
<header>
    <h1>About</h1>
    <div class="subtitle">We sell apples, yay!</div>
</header>

<style>
    header .subtitle{ color: blue; }
</style>
```

Comment: Thanks for the correct term. If not for nikc's answer, I would've accepted yours(Too bad you can't accept multiple answers if they're all equally helpful) +1 for you :)

Comment: What about site header? What should I use for, say, the blog description? Since `<header>` is already the container I can't put another `<header>` to it. In the past people used `<hgroup>` (with `<h1>` and `<h2>` inside), but since it's not supported anymore...

Comment: The applicable term is "subtitle," not "byline."

Answer (score 5):

I really liked Toby Inkster's suggestion here: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-html/2010Nov/0405.html as an alternative to HTML5's proposed `<hgroup>` element which seems to be a difficult concept for many web authors to grasp. (See the start of that thread by Bruce Lawson.) Toby suggests:

```
<h2>
  <span>About<span>
  <small>We sell apples, yay!</small>
</h2>
```

Comment: Using the `small` tag in the header as a subheading is [not advised by the HTML working group](http://html5doctor.com/howto-subheadings/).

Comment: If you use Bootstrap it can come very handy.

Answer (score 2):

In the case that the byline is actually a quote you should use blockquote.

```
<h2>About Us</h2>
<blockquote class="byline"><p>We Sell Apples Yay!</p></blockquote>
```

Answer (score 1):

I personally think your second option is the best. "About" is the title of a section, but the 'subheading' or more of a descriptive nature than a section title/header. You could use `<strong>` instead of a span to indicate it's a little more important than the rest of the text yet not a heading.

If they really are subheadings, like

## About

**About us**

Text about us

**About this website**

Text about this website

You should use `<h3>` for the sub-headings.

Comment: Except that, if you use `<strong>` to denote subheadings, you lose the ability to use the same tag to indicate important bits of content/body text.

Comment: I edited my answer, if it's an actual subheading you should use an H element, but if it's just a little more important text (whether it's inside a paragraph or more of an important subline) I'd use strong. I don't think that devaluates the strong element if used in other parts as well. It really depends on whether the subheading is actually some sort of heading/title or more of an introductory line or something.